# FileNotFoundException при обращении к API

Tags: android, json, kotlin, api

Пишу приложение для Погоды , взял Api  https://openweathermap.org/api .
Если верно написать город, то получаю правильный JSON, который дальше разбираю и использую.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но если указать город с ошибкой, сервер отдает JSON
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При получении такого JSON приложение падает, если обернуть в try/catch это спасает, но как обработать разные ошибки сервера?

Попробовал напрямую выводить в консоль запрос к серверу, при правильном названии города получаю JSON, если убрать одну букву то получаю FileNotFoundException. Куда копать дальше?

```
fun main() {

    println(URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=kie&appid=473e5a7943f7f083bb2de54617c79d7a&units=metric&lang=ru").readText())
```

}

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=kie&appid=473e5a7943f7f083bb2de54617c79d7a&units=metric&lang=ru
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1993)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1161)
at kotlin.io.TextStreamsKt.readBytes(ReadWrite.kt:150)
at MainKt.main(Main.kt:5)
at MainKt.main(Main.kt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы получаете ошибку `FileNotFoundException`, это означает, что сервер не может найти запрошенный ресурс, в данном случае - город. Вы можете обработать эту ошибку, используя конструкцию try/catch и отдельно обрабатывать ошибку `FileNotFoundException`. Например:

```
try {
    val url = URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=kie&appid=473e5a7943f7f083bb2de54617c79d7a&units=metric&lang=ru")
    val json = url.readText()
    // далее работаем с json
} catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
    // обработка ошибки FileNotFoundException
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // общая обработка ошибок
}
```

Кроме того, вы можете использовать код ответа HTTP, который будет возвращен сервером, чтобы определить, какую ошибку сервер вернул. Например, если сервер вернул код `404`, это означает, что запрошенный ресурс не найден. Код ответа можно получить, используя метод `getResponseCode()` у объекта `HttpURLConnection`. Например:

```
val url = URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=kie&appid=473e5a7943f7f083bb2de54617c79d7a&units=metric&lang=ru")
val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
val responseCode = connection.responseCode
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) {
    // обработка ошибки 404
} else {
    val json = url.readText()
    // далее работаем с json
}
```

Ведь сервер возвращает `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Comment: Изучив документацию Api, нашел ошибки которые может вернуть сервер, и обработал их вашим вторым способом. Я был уверен, что можно распарсить ошибку и потом ее обработать. Буду глубже изучать сети. Спасибо.